# flow of functions in angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I am new to protractor and angular js. I want to automate the test of web application using protractor and angular js. The web application has a login page followed by the main page that contains drop downs and input field. I have written the protractor code to do the test to login to the application. But after that It does not execute the function I wrote for the click on drop-down my question is where should I place the function for the drop-down selection. The flow I have is ...

```
   var  username = element(by.model('login.username'));
   var password = element(by.model('login.password'));
   var goButton = element(by.buttonText("Login"));
   function login_page(a, b) {     
      username.sendKeys(a);
      password.sendKeys(b);
      goButton.click();
    }
    beforeEach(function() {
       browser.get('my_url');
     })
    function seldrop(element, optionNum) {
       console.log('in seldrop');
       var selectDropdownbyNum = function ( element, optionNum ) {  
       if (optionNum){
           var options = element.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-toggle')   
           .then(function(options){
            options[optionNum].click();
            console.log(options);
       });
     }
  }
  }

  it('put in values', function() {
  login_pg('usrname', 'passwd');
  const selector = seldrop(element,'3');
    colsole.log(selector);
   });
```

When I execute the JS through protractor, It does show success but just succeeds login that is it.
The seldrop function doesn't seem to be called. Is it in the proper sequence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see element variable [seldrop(element,'3')] defined as global variable or inside it block. So it might be passing undefined value.

I don't see a problem with the order in which you have defined functions(As per my knowledge about execution context in javascript) . But as a standard it would be nice if you could keep all the functions together before beforeEach block

Comment: I added var mySelect = $('3'); to the global section and used this variable in "it" section but now I get  element.querySelectorAll is not a function
error

Comment: Could you please update your code here with the latest code in your system